# R: Compute Cohen's d based on t-statistic of a coefficient in multiple linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, difference, calculation

I'm looking at age- and sex-adjusted group differences in a continuous variable of interest. As done in other studies in my field, I want to calculate Cohen's d based on **contrasts extracted from a multiple linear regression model**.

The original formula (Nakagawa & Cuthill, 2007) is as follows:

[image: Credit: Nakagawa & Cuthill, 2007]

n1 = sample size in Group 1

n2 = sample size in Group 2

df' = degrees of freedom used for a corresponding t value in a linear model

t = t-statistic corresponding to the contrast of interest

So far I've attempted to apply this in R, but the results are looking strange (much larger effect sizes than expected).

Here's some simulated data:

```
library(broom)

df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006,1007, 1008, 1009, 1010),
                Group = as.numeric(c('0','1','0','0','1','1','0','1','0','1')),
                age = as.numeric(c('23','28','30','15','7','18','29','27','14','22')),
                sex = as.numeric(c('1','0','1','0','0','1','1','0','0','1')),
                test_score = as.numeric(c('18','20','19','15','20','23','19','25','10','14')))

# run lm and extract regression coefficients

model <- lm(test_score ~ Group + age + sex, data = df)
tidy_model <- tidy(model)

tidy_model

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#term        estimate std.error statistic p.value
#<chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1 (Intercept)   11.1       4.41     2.52    0.0451
# 2 Group          4.63      2.65     1.75    0.131 
# 3 age            0.225     0.198    1.13    0.300 
# 4 sex            0.131     2.91     0.0452  0.965 

t_statistic <- tidy_model[2,4] # = 1.76
n <- 5 #(equal n of participants in Group1 as in Group2)
cohens_d <- t_statistic*(n + n)/(sqrt(n * n) * sqrt(1)) # 1 dof for 1 estimated parameter (group contrast)

cohens_d  # = 3.518096
```

Could you please flag up where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your `sex` column in `df` has more values than the other columns. Please correct so I can be sure I am reproducing your example correctly.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting @qdread - this has been corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the degrees of freedom to 1. However, you actually have 6 degrees of freedom which you can see if you type: `summary(model)`.
If you set your degrees of freedom to 6 your Cohen's d will be ~1.7 which should be more inline with what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I've run it with the model dof as you've suggested and with my actual data but still get some oddly high values (e.g., 4.6)

Comment: Just to follow-up - the paper seems to explicity mentions the dof associated with the actual t-statistic and not the overall model. But perhaps I've misunderstood it? https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Effect-size%2C-confidence-interval-and-statistical-a-Nakagawa-Cuthill/f2ba29f3119cdedc147ac703e8d34bd8eed3d00b

Comment: The degrees of freedom for the t-statistic should be 6 as well (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803328/degrees-of-freedom-of-t-test-in-multiple-regression). You can confirm this is what the model summary is using: `2 * pt(1.747, df = 6, lower.tail = FALSE)` is about `0.131` which is the p-value shown in the model summary.